# Deploying Grails Atmosphere app in JBoss 7

Tags: grails, jboss, websocket, atmosphere

Greeting,

I'm trying to make [this example](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/chat) work in Grails 2.1 using [atmosphere plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/atmosphere). When running in development environment on Tomcat it does not work, probably because Tomcat does not support web-services.
So I'm deploying it on JBoss 7.1. It does not work as well. And the following exception could be found in the log file

```
AtmosphereFramework exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The servlet or filters
that are being used by this request do not support async operation
```

I found the [article](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1251) related to async servlets support in Grails. Seems that `Servlet3AsyncWebXmlProcessor` should add async support to web.xml. But somebody should invoke it.
I think that atmosphere plugin is responsible for allowing async communication.

Have I missed something? Could you please help to make it work on AS7?

Ideally, I would like to figure out the way of running atmosphere applications in development environment? Is it possible?

Comment: do you have app.servlet.version=3.0 in your application.properties?